# What is the point in using a "using" declaration in this context?

Tags: c++, templates, using

Let's say I have two classes as below. Is there any advantage or disadvantage of using a `using` declaration in the derived class, to specify that we will be using the base class version of the method?

**More importantly, is the *altered derived class* the same as the *original derived class*?**

```cpp
// BASE CLASS                        
template <typename T>               
class base {                        
public:                             
    base (T val): value(val){}      
                                    
    void val(int i) {               
        value += i;                 
    }                               

private:                            
    T value;                        
};                                  
                                    
// DERIVED CLASS                                    
template <typename T>                               
class derived: public base<T> {                     
public:                                             
    derived (T val): value2(val), base<T>(val){}    

    void val(int k) {                               
        base<T>::val(k);                            
        value2 += k;                                
    }                                               

private:                                            
    T value2;                                       
};                                                  

// ALTERED DERIVED CLASS                                    
template <typename T>
class derived: public base<T> {
public:
    derived (T val): value2(val), base<T>(val){}
                                                    
    using base<T>::val;                             

    void val(int k) {
        base<T>::val(k);
        value2 += k;
    }

private:
    T value2;
};
```

Comment: Can you reformat the 2nd derived class to be shown below the base class instead of showing them side by side. It looks strange side by side and is hard to read IMO.

Comment: Hi @Albert, Done. Moved it.

Comment: If `base` were to add any other overloads to `val`, such as a no-args `vall()`, those would be callable from Derived Class but shadowed in Altered Derived Class.

Comment: @thumalamanish You did?

Comment: @NathanPierson don't you mean the other way round?

Comment: I think plan was to enable overload for `val` , but since arguments in both cases have same type, this is pointless. Anyway fact that `val` do not depend directly on `T` is kind of strange.

Comment: Here is some demo https://godbolt.org/z/GWchafxjE

Comment: @Caleth When I wrote my comment, "Derived Class" had the `using` line and "Altered Derived Class" did not

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, if nothing else changes, you won't observe any differences, but it's not exactly the same in general.

The `using` in the derived will pull all the corresponding symbols from the base class into derived's scope.  The difference is pretty clear here:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    void foo(int) { std::cout << "Base::foo(int)\n"; }
};
struct Derived : Base {
    // using Base::foo;
    void foo(long) { std::cout << "Derived::foo(long)\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.foo(123);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/TdEYsbesv

Output is:

```
Derived::foo(long)
```

but if you uncomment the `using` in Derived, then the output changes to:

```
Base::foo(int)
```

The reason is that the name lookup stops once a scope matches the name it's seeking.  Without the `using`, once a name found in the derived class, it will not look in the base class for more overloads--even if there's a better match there.

The `using` makes the base class symbols appear alongside the derived names, so that the combination of base+derived overload set is searched when a name is looked up on a derived class.  (If a function with the same signature is provided in both base and derived, the derived version will still be picked if you invoke the call on a derived object.)